# GRPC target method can\'t be resolved.-@google-cloud/speech API

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-speech

I want to convert Text to speech and speech to text. I'm using google cloud APIs for this. Text to speech is working fine.But speech to text  is not working when I install @google-cloud/speech and @google-cloud/text-to-speech libraries in the same project.I understood that there is a conflict between the dependencies of the libraries but coudnt find a solution.

Error Log:

```
{ Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: GRPC target method can't be resolved.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:175:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:341:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:304:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:116:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:155:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (\SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:141:18)
    at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/SampleNodeJs\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:273:14)
    at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emit (internal/http2/core.js:236:8)
  code: 12,
  details: 'GRPC target method can\'t be resolved.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} },
  note:
   'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

**Package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "samplenodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^4.1.0",
    "@google-cloud/text-to-speech": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security"
  }
}
```

Package Initialisation:

```
  // Creates a client
    const appConfig= {
        projectId: 'ssssssssssss',
        keyFilename: './key.json'
    }
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient(appConfig);

// Creates a client
    const client = new speech.SpeechClient(appConfig);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, I was using the same key.json file for both the packages.I solved it by creating copy of key file and initializing it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error, it was just **updating** your packages and **checking** their compatibility  (google-api-core, google-api-nodejs-client,..)